# WPF Multithreaded UI - Usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, composite

I have seen some code samples of multi-threaded UIs in WPF using multiple windows where each window runs on it's own UI thread. I'm curious though - is there a way to accomplish this with embedded controls?

For example lets say I have usercontrol1 and usercontrol2 both embedded in Window1. Usercontrol1 starts to spin and blocks the main UI thread. The window and usercontrol2 are effected. Is there a way to make it so even if usercontrol1 blocks, Window1 + usercontrol2 are still responsive?

Let us assume we don't control the developers of usercontrol1 - so we can't tell them to make their control behave.

Let us also assume the exchange of data between usercontrol1 + 2 is a must.

Should I be exploring something like AddIn's?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "run" the controls on another thread (as with Winforms, the controls themselves must be created and run on the same thread as the top-level parent), but there's nothing stopping you from *initiating* actions on another thread from a user control. You just have to ensure that you use the `Dispatcher` to `Invoke` any operations that will have a direct effect upon the control itself. Behind-the-scenes processing can be done entirely on another thread, though; it's just the physical updating of the UI that has to be invoked back via the `Dispatcher`.

*EDIT:* After the question was edited, no, there is no way to move all of the "work" that a particular component performs to another thread. If you can't control the development of the component in question, then you're at the mercy of the developer and where he decides to execute the code.

Comment: How does that work with Add-ins that are in a different appdomain?

Comment: Downvoter care to comment why? This is, as far as I'm aware, a correct answer.

Comment: @Dr.HappyPants: I'm not sure what you mean; are you talking about communicating with something running in another AppDomain? Can you give a more specific example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm fuzzy on the details so bear with me, If you look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/08/06/appdomain-isolated-wpf-add-ins-jesse-kaplan.aspx this is a mechanism for having wpf add-ins isolated to different appdomains. I was just curious how this relates to what you posted above (if at all). Unfortunately, while your answer may end up being correct it doesn't help me move forward. I can't tell usercontrol1 in this example to do less on the UI thread, it's very possible they are for example a rogue control or a rogue add-in.

Comment: To some extent what I'm trying to understand is if something like Google Chrome's Architecture is possible in WPF. For example if page spins out of control or crashes in Google Chrome, the rest of your tabs are unaffected. I'm trying to accomplish an add-in model like this, where I can load third party controls but keep the core app safe from misbehavior.

Comment: @Dr.HappyPants: The Addin's framework is isolating the controls by appdomain, but you still fundamentally have no control over which thread is executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

As on the top you have visual ([Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx)) which is inheriting from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx). It is designed as STA threading model, in which single thread is accessing the object methods and properties.

That is why both controls must be created in the same thread as Window.

If you need to exchange data between controls and you are not controlling developers of those controls I would consider using PRISM or other MVVM framework. In prism you have [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) which is basically subscriber publisher pattern your UserControl1 can publish something  and the other one if it's subscribed will receive that.